# Dynamic SQL Clause Returns Empty Set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert a SQL Statement that calculates a Moving Average to a Dynamic SQL statement that executes a stored procedure, but the Dynamic SQL clause is not returning the same results as the original statement and I don't know why.

Here is a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE(DT Date, FLD varchar(100), FLD2 varchar(100), VAL INT)

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES('2020-01-01', 'SRS', 'PX', 101),
('2020-01-02', 'SRS', 'PX', 95),
('2020-01-03', 'SRS', 'PX', 104),
('2020-01-04', 'SRS', 'PX', 98),
('2020-01-05', 'SRS', 'PX', 103),
('2020-01-06', 'SRS', 'PX', 115),
('2020-01-07', 'SRS', 'PX', 94),
('2020-01-08', 'SRS', 'PX', 103),
('2020-01-09', 'SRS', 'PX', 93),
('2020-01-10', 'SRS', 'PX', 105)
```

Here is the Moving Average Calculation for 3 time steps:

```
WITH cte_ma(DT, RowNumber, Ma) AS (
SELECT DT, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DT ASC) AS RowNumber,
AVG(VAL) OVER (ORDER BY DT ASC ROWS 2 PRECEDING) AS MA
FROM dbo.Example
WHERE FLD = 'SRS' AND FLD2 = 'PX')
SELECT 'The Name' as Ticker, DT, IIF (RowNumber > 2, MA, NULL) AS 'LSTPX'
FROM cte_ma
```

This returns the correct results.  What I need to do is convert this to a stored procedure where people can specify the number of time units to use for the moving average.  The problem is that the `ORDER BY` clause does not allow varaibles to be inserted.  So I am attempting to wrap it up in a Dynamic SQL statement first.

The moving average window, value for `FLD` and `FLD2` and the name of the ticker in the second `SELECT` clause should be parameters in the stored procedure.

Here is the Dynamic SQL/Stored Procedure that I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sample_ma](@value_name AS varchar(100),
                       @period AS varchar(100),
                       @BBG AS varchar(100),
                       @FLD AS varchar(100))

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'WITH CTE_MA (DT, RowNumber, MA)
    AS (
        SELECT DT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DT ASC) AS RowNumber,
        AVG(VAL) OVER (ORDER BY DT ASC ROWS ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(int, @period) - 1) + ' PRECEDING) AS MA
                FROM dbo.Example
                WHERE FLD = '' + @BBG + '' AND FLD2 = '' + @FLD + '') SELECT '' + @value_name + '' as Ticker, DT, IIF (RowNumber > 2, MA, NULL) AS LSTPX
FROM CTE_MA'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END
```

This returns an empty set when I run `EXECUTE dbo.sample_ma 'The Name', '3', 'SRS', 'PX'` to calculate the 3 day moving average like I had above.  Please note that it's important to be able to perform subtraction on the parameter for the moving window because it will be used multiple ways in a larger statement.

This example is abbreviated for clarity.

Comment: You debug dynamic SQL by using the `print` statement to print your dynamic SQL (`@sql`) instead of running it. Then you have static SQL which you can compare to your original static SQL and you can find what is different.

Comment: You've still got `RowNumber > 2` hardcoded in your dynamic sql. Shouldn't that be `'RowNumber > ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(int, @period) - 1)` ?

Comment: @DeanOC thank you, noted.

Comment: This code should throw compilation error instead of showing empty result because of what   @gordon-linoff mentioned below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing the values in as parameters.  But if you printed out the statement, I think it might be obvious.

You have these lines like this:

```
'WHERE FLD = '' + @BBG + '' AND FLD2 = '' + @FLD + '') SELECT '' + @value_name + '' as Ticker, DT, IIF (RowNumber > 2, MA, NULL) AS LSTPX'
```

This does not pass the values into the string.  You need more single quotes:

```
WHERE FLD = ''' + @BBG + ''' AND FLD2 = ''' + @FLD + ''') SELECT ''' + @value_name + ''' as Ticker, DT, IIF (RowNumber > 2, MA, NULL) AS LSTPX
```

Of course, I'll say once again -- these should be *parameters* not munged into the query string.

Comment: I can't use the window size as a parameter because the `ORDER BY` clause requires a literal value, and it has to get inserted somewhere.  So if I have to use Dynamic SQL then I'm not sure how to use the other fields as pure parameters since the query must be encoded as text.